# How to keep JS window on screen at page reload

Tags: javascript, php, css

Im still in learning progress so thats why I turn to you guys!

I did a sample website where I have a button in the menu for a login form.
When pressed the javascript tells the class to put display: none; to display.

Issue I have right now is that when I try to login on the website and the credentials are wrong the website refreshes with a header location of the issue message, making the login box dissapear / resets the default value of the box to display none.

How can I achive that the box only closes if a person click the login box "x" or if the success login is active?

```
  document.getElementById('login-nav').addEventListener('click',
function() {
  document.querySelector('.login-box').style.display = 'flex';
});

document.querySelector('.login-box-x').addEventListener('click',
  function() {
    document.querySelector('.login-box').style.display = 'none';
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQAEN.png)

Comment: you can use something that persists, like a cookie

Comment: ... or add the style to the login box in the PHP if the login fails, or use AJAX to send the form.

Comment: @teemu I have the php code ready that says if someone fails to login. Issue is that the header location makes the url change to the faultcode that gives the echo. In the same time the login box dissapears because the site "refreshes". Which makes the display none

Comment: Yes, then just include the style to the element when you know the login has failed.

Comment: @teemu could you give an example? Im really not so far in learning yet so I dont know what to search for. I tried to google how to compaire the urls with javascript but I guess Im wrong way in thinking?

Comment: I've no clue what you've on the server-side code, but [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1jdo5yq/) demonstrates the idea.